# Is it a good way to implement iterator?

Tags: python

I have some question about good practice.
So say we have some class which we want to use as iterator.
It class should returns first some header and then returns its blocks.
I see two ways for this case:

1. The first one is "classic". Return in **iter** methods self and put some logic in **next** method, like:

```
def __next(self):
    if not self._header_was_returned:
        self._header_was_returned = True
        return self._header
    if self._index >= self._count_blocks:
        raise StopIteration
    block = self._blocks[self._index]
    self._index += 1
    return block
```

2. Or another one, in this case used less code, just implenet **iter** method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yeild self._header
    for block in self._blocks:
        yield block
```

Another case is create some class `IteratorForMyBlockClass` and implements ``**_next**``` method there, but it similar for the first case.

Updated:

From "Fluent Python" (Chapter 14).
Main class is itarable (but not iterator).
Main class should return some `IteratorClass` in `__iter__` method.
And in Iterator class I should put some logic:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, header, blocks):
        self._header = header
        self._blocks = blocks
    def __iter__(self):
        return MainClassIterator(self._header, self._blocks)

class MainClassIterator:
    def __init__(self, header, blocks):
        self._header = header
        self._blocks = blocks
        self._index = 0
        self._header_was_returned = False
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if not self._header_was_returned:
             self._header_was_returned = True
             return self._header
        if self._index >= len(self._blocks):
             raise StopIteration        
        block = self._blocks[self._index]
        self._index += 1
        return block
```

Is that a good solution?

Comment: Please do *not* return `self` in `__iter__` if that iterator is stateful (nearly all iterators are). If you would use multiple iterators concurrently, things will go wrong.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the concepts of "iterator" and "iterable". Are you aware there is a difference, and are you sure you want these objects to be iterators rather than iterable?

Comment: So...should implement own Iterator class which will be returned in iter method? And put in Iterator class next method like in the first case?

Comment: I updated my question, please check it

Comment: in the second case where you only implement `__iter__`, you are not implementing an iterator, you are implementing an *iterable*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a `MainClassIterator`. Since a generator function always returns an iterator, an easy solution would be to put this `__iter__` in `MainClass`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self._header
    yield from self._blocks
```